# Site works for IE but, not Edge?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have a site http://cosmicsearch.org that crashes when you try to type something when you use the new Edge Browser which makes it even weirder it works great on IE.

How can I fix it?

Oh this is what I used to make it work for IE

```html
<!--[if IE]>
    <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ilovecode1/ieify.js/master/ieify.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="blendTrans(duration=0)"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Page-Exit" content="blendTrans(duration=0)"/>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I just tested version 25.10586 of Microsoft Edge, and saw no crash. Do you have all available updates installed? (Check Windows Update) Note also that conditional comments don't work in Microsoft Edge, and haven't worked since IE 10.

Comment: When I press enter it crashed.

Comment: I understand. Do you have all available updates installed?

Comment: Yes I have the latest updates

Comment: might be something I installed

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer are you testing? Also, which document mode is the page served in? (Check top-right of F12 Developer Tools). Lastly, does Microsoft Edge have any errors or other ouput in the F12 console?

Comment: No errors in console and IE is the one in windows 10.